# Algorithmic Game Theory as an undergrad

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, undergraduate, algorithms

I am an undergrad going into my junior year this semester. I really wanted to explore algorithmic game theory, as my university has some excellent professors in that field. However, as my undergrad is drawing to a close, it is seeming increasingly likely that I will not be able to do this in my undergrad if I don't step up and teach myself the basics. However, looking online, I am unable to find anything "basic" for intro students to the subject. Would you have any recommendations on how to start learning algorithmic game theory?

I am well versed in regular game theory

Comment: Talk to the profs.

Comment: @philipxy - They don't respond

Comment: Learn game theory first. Like economic game theory, Nash equilibria, etc.

Comment: You can find some lecture notes here: https://ml2.inf.ethz.ch/courses/agt/ I took the course and if I remember correctly there weren't too many prerequisites, although I did have some familiarity with game theory. The lecture notes are a bit sparse, so I recommend using them as a study guide and looking for complementary material on the same topics as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

try Tim Roughgarden online AGT course & book
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEGCF-WLh2RJBqmxvZ0_ie-mleCFhi2N4

and those 2 lectures by Constantinos Daskalakis for the PPAD class
https://youtu.be/TUbfCY_8Dzs
https://youtu.be/Ih0cPR745fM

and Papa Dimitriou  2 lectures in Simons Institute
https://youtu.be/ggi2PZbO0oQ
https://youtu.be/0cyR_fpOvOc

Tim Roughgarden is one of the pioneers in the AGT field, never knew anyone teach it or even studied it without referencing his 20 lectures book. Besides he is the original source for the Price of Anarchy(his PhD), I think participated in the Big USA spectrum auction. For the same reason I added Constantinos for the PPAD class it's his PhD, I personally understood it better from him. Papa Dimitriou is also like their mentor/GOD Father, but not too many lectures available online for him. Thanks u reminded me to add more resources

Answer (score 1):

**Books:**

1. The standard reference on Algorithmic Game Theory is the book by Nisan, Tardos, Roughgarden, and Vazirani.

Algorithmic Game Theory
http://www.cambridge.org/journals/nisan/downloads/Nisan_Non-printable.pdf

2. Another book on AGT is by Kevin Leyton-Brown from UBC and Yoav Shoham from Stanford:

Multi-Agent Systems: Algorithmic, Game-Theoretic and Logical Foundations

A free electronic copy has been made available by the authors as well:
http://www.masfoundations.org/mas.pdf

I think there are half a dozen books by Roughgarden with **"Twenty Lectures on Algorithmic Game Theory"** being one of the best books for beginners. All Books are available on amazon.

**Courses:**

If you're interested in lecture notes and video lectures on Algorithmic Game Theory, then I would strongly urge you to have a look at Tim Roughgarden's course website:

Algorithmic Game Theory (CS364A), Fall 2013
His lectures are amazing and surprisingly easy to grasp, especially considering the theoretical nature of the subject matter.

There's also a sequel course on Mechanism Design if you're interested:
Frontiers in Mechanism Design (CS364B), Winter 2014

If you're looking to brush up on a few game theory fundamentals you could go through the following two courses offered by Coursera:

Introductory Course on Game Theory
https://www.coursera.org/course/gametheory

Advanced Applications of Game Theory: Auctions and Social Choice Theory
https://www.coursera.org/course/gametheory2

Answer (score 0):

You could: Try some online classes/tutorials, e.g., on YouTube, read textbooks recommended by university classes (at your level), or buy the highest ranked textbooks on Amazon.